# index was outside the bounds of the array in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm getting the following error thrown:

```
index was outside the bounds of the array
```

When using this code:

```
con.Open()
            qur = "select Username,password from registration where Username='" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qur, con)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows() Then
                dr.Read()
                Session("us1") = dr.GetValue(11).ToString()
                Session("ps1") = dr.GetValue(12).ToString()
                If Session("us1") = TextBox1.Text And Session("ps1") = TextBox2.Text Then
                    Response.Redirect("APP.aspx")
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

Could someone please point out where/why it's going wrong?

Comment: put break point and see wherther the dr has these 11 and 12th items
You are getting this error as there is nothing at 11 or may be 12th position.

Comment: make sure `dr` have 13 items.

Comment: Note your code is wide open to sql injection - use parameterised queries whenever possible

Answer (score 1):

Check your ordinals. You might be giving an index which does not exist.

Index starts from 0. Instead of 11,12 you might want to try with 10, 11 for GetValue

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect the problem lies with:

```
Session("us1") = dr.GetValue(11).ToString()
Session("ps1") = dr.GetValue(12).ToString()
```

However, don't use ordinals use column names:

```
Session("us1") = dr("column1").ToString()
Session("ps1") = dr("column2").ToString()
```

Ordering can easily change blowing up your ordinals. By using column names you're not dependent on the order so you won't get an index error.

If the column doesn't exist you WILL get another kind of error however.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get values for fields that don't exist:

```
dr.GetValue(11)
```

and

```
dr.GetValue(12)
```

Note that your query is only selecting two columns (username and password)

```
 select Username,password
```

Either use `GetValue(0)` and `GetValue(1)` or use column names `dr("Username")` and `dr("password")`